# check session cookies on different localhost port number

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I'm using flask as a backend and React.js as front end. Whenever user login, session is stored on web browser but upon inspecting it, there is no session. I realized that it only checked the session side of frontend and not the backend. Is there any way i can see the backend localhost sessions

[Server Side where I'm storing session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqh2G.png)

[localhost 3000 is of front end and inspecting section doesnt show session of port 5000 where server side is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZCXX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the api for check the backend session, you can check that space.

examples

```
from flask import Flask, session, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "ABCD"

@app.route('/set/<value>')
def set(value):
    print(value)
    session["username"] = value
    return jsonify("userName is {}".format(value))

@app.route('/check')
def check():
    print(session)
    return jsonify("check the flask server log")
```

Comment: i'm doing it like this but inspecting element section on browser was not checking port of backend 
like back end was on port 5000 and front end was on 3000 
when checked, it only showed localhost:3000 but not the 5000 one